# Cannot deploy application on websphere

Tags: ejb-3.0, derby, websphere-7

I am working with an application that uses the following technologies: Java, EJB 3, JPA, Websphere, and Oracle.
We do not make use of derby at all, however, when I try to deploy the ear to websphere it keeps giving me the following error:

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver (initialization failure)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:140)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDataSource.findDriver(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDataSource.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDataSource.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedXADataSource.setupResourceAdapter(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedXADataSource.getXAConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.InternalGenericDataStoreHelper$1.run(InternalGenericDataStoreHelper.java:1221)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.InternalGenericDataStoreHelper.getPooledConnection(InternalGenericDataStoreHelper.java:1258)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.WSRdbDataSource.getPooledConnection(WSRdbDataSource.java:2308)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.WSManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.createManagedConnection(WSManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.java:1598)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.FreePool.createManagedConnectionWithMCWrapper(FreePool.java:2034)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.FreePool.createOrWaitForConnection(FreePool.java:1711)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.PoolManager.reserve(PoolManager.java:2471)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ConnectionManager.allocateMCWrapper(ConnectionManager.java:1059)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ConnectionManager.allocateConnection(ConnectionManager.java:696)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcDataSource.getConnection(WSJdbcDataSource.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcDataSource.getConnection(WSJdbcDataSource.java:635)
    at com.ibm.ws.extensionhelper.db.impl.DatabaseHelperImpl$DSWrapper.getConnection(DatabaseHelperImpl.java:1584)
    at com.ibm.ws.extensionhelper.db.impl.DatabaseHelperImpl.getConnection(DatabaseHelperImpl.java:746)
    at com.ibm.ws.extensionhelper.db.impl.DatabaseHelperImpl.getConnection(DatabaseHelperImpl.java:1354)
    at com.ibm.ws.extensionhelper.db.impl.DatabaseHelperImpl.connect(DatabaseHelperImpl.java:544)
    at com.ibm.ws.extensionhelper.db.impl.DatabaseHelperImpl.initialize(DatabaseHelperImpl.java:497)
    ... 75 more
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: sealing violation: package org.apache.derby.impl.store.raw.data is sealed
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:487)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:451)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$300(URLClassLoader.java:79)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$ClassFinder.run(URLClassLoader.java:1034)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:284)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:429)
    at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.findClass(ExtClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:653)
    at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.loadClass(ExtClassLoader.java:90)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:619)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:275)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:69)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:540)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:451)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$300(URLClassLoader.java:79)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$ClassFinder.run(URLClassLoader.java:1034)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:284)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:429)
    at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.findClass(ExtClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:653)
    at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.loadClass(ExtClassLoader.java:90)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:619)
    at java.lang.Class.forNameImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:139)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.getImplementations(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.getDefaultImplementations(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.runWithState(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.FileMonitor.(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.startMonitor(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.jdbc.JDBCBoot.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver.boot(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver.(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:200)
    at java.lang.Class.forNameImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:172)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.EJBContainerImpl.timerDBExists(EJBContainerImpl.java:2091)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.EJBContainerImpl.startModule(EJBContainerImpl.java:2550)
    ... 67 more

By the way, my jdbcprovider and datasource are properly configured. I just don't understand what is the relationship between my application and derby.

Any ideas? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you look at any of the suggestions in this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597947/issue-with-noclassdeffounderror-error-in-a-web-environment-spring-wicket-derby-j

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IBM Websphere uses Derby as internal database. Try to restart the server and examine server logs at startup. It is most likely that you have a server configuration problem and your application is ok. By the way, have you tried to deploy other applications on this server?