# Why driver is still missing?

Tags: java, derby, classnotfoundexception

I am trying to use Java DB for app only storage.

### Environment Variables:

```
CLASSPATH:
%JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib;%DERBY_HOME%\lib\derby.jar
DERBY_HOME:
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\db
Path:
%DERBY_HOME%\bin
```

No changes in eclipse configurations was done and i cannot include it to build path(it somehow will be considered as third party library, which is not allowed)
When i type "sysinfo" in cmd it tells me Db is instaled and list packages and other info.

### Code:

```
   public class Main {
        private static String dbURL = "jdbc:derby:AssertDB;user=me;password=mine;create=true";
        private static Connection con = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        setDBSystemDir();
        createConnection();
        CookiesTable pTable = new CookiesTable(con);
        try {
            pTable.createTable();
            pTable.populateTable();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // load files
        // parse files to tables
        // retrive SQL statment
        // print result

    }

    private static void setDBSystemDir() {
        // Decide on the db system directory: <userhome>/.addressbook/
        String userHomeDir = System.getProperty("user.home", ".");
        String systemDir = userHomeDir + "/.asertdb";

        // Set the db system directory.
        System.setProperty("derby.system.home", systemDir);
    }

    private static void createConnection() {

        try {
            Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver").newInstance();
            // Get a connection
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL);
        } catch (Exception except) {
            System.out.println("DRIVER DRROOOOOP");
            except.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

### Exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
    at com.tuto.p4.Main.createConnection(Main.java:44)
    at com.tuto.p4.Main.main(Main.java:13)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.tuto.p4.CookiesTable.createTable(CookiesTable.java:29)
    at com.tuto.p4.Main.main(Main.java:16)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Issue with NoClassDefFoundError error in a web environment Spring/Wicket/Derby/Jetty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597947/issue-with-noclassdeffounderror-error-in-a-web-environment-spring-wicket-derby-j)

Comment: i read it, tried it and could not solve problem

Comment: For almost all types of applications the environment variable `CLASS_PATH` is ignored.

Comment: I don't understand why you can't put the JARs on the Eclipse build path. Can you please explain "it somehow will be considered as third party library, which is not allowed" better?

Comment: Note: `%JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib` is not a valid entry on the classpath. First of all, Java will automatically add it (so there is really no need to specify it) and secondly, this won't add the JAR in that folder to the classpath. Instead, it just adds the whole folder as classpath resources (so you can now load `rt.jar` but not the code *inside of it*)

Comment: I see that it is run via main method. The CLASSPATH environment variable should not be ignored. Are you running it from command line? Are you setting variables on the command line before you run? If you are setting variables on command line, do not set classpath before derby home. Also try enclosing paths with spaces within double quotes.  Also try to specify classpath as a java option - java -cp "yourdriverjarpath";otherjar.jar;yourclassesDir Main

Comment: Try java -verbose:class to get more insight into how the JRE is accessing your classpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refering to the documentation there are two things to do in case you get a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver` if you run the SampleApp.

1. [Configure Embedded Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/papers/DerbyTut/install_software.html#derby_configure)
2. [Verify Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/papers/DerbyTut/install_software.html#derby_verify)

As you said that you checked sysinfo I would try it with adding `derby.jar` and `derbytools.jar` even if the tools are optional.

Or you can compare the SampleApp to your App....

Answer (score 0):

Include derbytools.jar, derbyclient.jar as well.

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://db.apache.org/derby/papers/DerbyTut/install_software.html), `derby.jar` should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.class.path"));`
before `Class.forName(...).newInstance()`

The output must contain a valid path to derby.jar.