# jetty server throw java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation while deploying

Tags: spring, hibernate, jetty

I deploy my war file in jetty server but it throws the following error. what are the possible way to solve this issue?

```
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving overridden method "com.system.maintanance$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$acf87b65.loadSystemName(Ljava/lang/
String;)Lcom/system/ControllSys;" the class loader (instance of org/eclipse/jetty/webapp/WebAppClassLoader) of the current class, com/system/maintanance$$EnhancerBySpringCGL
IB$$acf87b65, and its superclass loader (instance of org/eclipse/jetty/start/Classpath$Loader), have different Class objects for the type com/system/ControllSys used in the signature
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_20]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_20]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.defineClass(ReflectUtils.java:415) ~[spring-core-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:336) ~[spring-core-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generate(Enhancer.java:492) ~[spring-core-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:93) ~[spring-core-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:91) ~[spring-core-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache$2.call(LoadingCache.java:54) ~[spring-core-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_20]
```

Comment: What is `com.system.maintanance$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$acf87b65.loadSystemName(Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/system/ControllSys;` doing?  The error is because there's multiple different implementations of a class in different classloaders.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5610698/775715